# VBA Raise a Flag once a value is found

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm trying to raise a flag once a value is found using the `.Find` method. The problem is with the `.Find`. It isn't working. It should be raising a flag as true, but it isn't. The values exist within the `Repasse.Range("A2:A" LastFindRange)` it just isn't recognizing them. Any ideas?

```
Dim Book As Workbook
Dim Calypso As Worksheet
Dim Repasse As Worksheet
Dim LastFindRange as Long
Dim LastCalypso as Long
Dim Flag as Boolean

Set Book = Workbooks("Novo Email - Caixa Offshore")
Set Calypso = Workbooks("Novo Email - Caixa Offshore").Worksheets("Calypso")
Set Repasse = Book.Worksheets("Exceções Repasse")
LastFindRange = Repasse.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCalypso = Calypso.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastCalypso
Flag = True
On Error Resume Next
Set FindSting = Repasse.Range("A2:A" & LastFindRange).Find(Calypso.Range("D" & i).Value)
If FindString Is Nothing Then
    Flag = False
Else: Flag = True
End If
```

Comment: What's `LastFindRange`?

Comment: Remove the On Error Resume Next and check if there is an error being raised. Besides provide the values to your other variables so we can see if there is an error.

Comment: Please see the edit above. I included part of the code that has the variables defined. And I'm about to try and do it without the On error Resume next and see whatsup

Comment: Sure. I was under the impression that the code within VBA was considered to be macros. My bad.

Comment: Even stranger is that when I put the cursor over FindString for the times when it isn't working it doesn't say "Nothing". It returns the value that I'm looking for. But once, while debugging, I get to the if, it sets the flag as false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

I had FindString as the range and was using FindSting - without an "r".

So it was all a typo.

Comment: Mark this as an answer to your question, co it can be closed. Btw `typo <> Idiot` ;)

Comment: Here is a huge tip that will save you many hours of debugging...In the VBE, Tools -> Options -> Editor tab -> Require Variable Declaration.

This will insert the code "Option Explicit" at the top of every new module. Option Explicit is a VBA coder's best friend. By forcing you to declare your variables it takes care of typos like this. The first time you run your routine it gives you a compile error, Variable not Defined and highlights FindSting.

I would also suggest manually adding Option Explicit to the top of all of your existing modules.